# How to pass columns in two data frames to Haversine Function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, haversine

I'm new to the lat & long stuff.  I found a Haversine Function that looks interesting.  I have two data frames that I am trying to feed into the function, but I'm getting an error.

Here's the function.

```
import numpy as np

lon1 = df["longitude_fuze"]
lat1 = df["latitude_fuze"]
lon2 = df["longitude_air"]
lat2 = df["latitude_air"]

# Haversine
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    km = 6367 * c
    return km
```

I am trying to add that to a column in a data frame, like this.

```
df['haversine_dist'] = haversine(lon1,lat1,lon2,lat2)
```

The function compiles fine, but when I try to call it, I get this error.

```
df['haversine_dist'] = haversine(lon1,lat1,lon2,lat2)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-38-cc7e470610ee>", line 1, in <module>
    df['haversine_dist'] = haversine(lon1,lat1,lon2,lat2)

  File "<ipython-input-37-f357b0fc2e88>", line 16, in haversine
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

  File "C:\Users\ryans\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 129, in wrapper
    raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

Here are two data frames that I am testing.

```
# Import pandas library 
import pandas as pd 
  
# initialize list of lists 
data = [['NY', 'Uniondale', 'Nassau', '40.72', '-73.59'], 
        ['NY', 'Uniondale', 'Nassau', '40.72', '-73.59'],
        ['NY', 'Uniondale', 'Nassau', '40.72', '-73.59'],
        ['NY', 'NY', 'New York', '40.76', '73.98'],
        ['NY', 'NY', 'New York', '40.76', '73.98']] 
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df_result = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['state', 'city', 'county','latitude_fuze','longitude_fuze']) 
# print dataframe. 
df_result


data = [['New York', 'JFK', '40.63', '-73.60'], 
        ['New York', 'JFK', '40.64', '-73.78'],
        ['Los Angeles', 'LAX', '33.94', '-118.41'],
        ['Chicago', 'ORD', '40.98', '73.90'],
        ['San Francisco', 'SFO', '40.62', '73.38']] 
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df_airports = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['municipality_name', 'airport_code', 'latitude_air','longitude_air']) 
# print dataframe. 
df_airports
```

I found the function at this link.

https://kanoki.org/2019/12/27/how-to-calculate-distance-in-python-and-pandas-using-scipy-spatial-and-distance-functions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues I see here:

1. Longitude and latitude are still strings in the data-frames, so you will likely run into issues with the data types.
2. The implementation of `haversine` used here does not work out of the box with array-like objects for longitude and latitude.

---

The **data type issue** can easily be addressed with `astype`. For example you could use `lon1 = df["longitude_fuze"].astype(float)`. Or even better, change the type directly in you data-frame:

```py
dt_dict = {"longitude_fuze": float, "latitude_fuze": float, 
           "longitude_air": float, "latitude_air": float}
df = df.astype(dt_dict)
```

For **a hoversine function supporting array-like arguments**, since it is rather straight forward, I'd suggest to re-implement it so that it's numpy compatible. I went ahead and did that for you:

```py
import numpy as np

def haversine_array(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(lambda x: x/360.*(2*np.pi), [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = np.sin(dlat/2)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a)) 
    km = 6367 * c
    return km
```

---

Putting it together:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def haversine_array(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(lambda x: x/360.*(2*np.pi), [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = np.sin(dlat/2)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a)) 
    km = 6367 * c
    return km

# initialize list of lists 
data = [['NY', 'Uniondale', 'Nassau', '40.72', '-73.59'], 
        ['NY', 'Uniondale', 'Nassau', '40.72', '-73.59'],
        ['NY', 'Uniondale', 'Nassau', '40.72', '-73.59'],
        ['NY', 'NY', 'New York', '40.76', '73.98'],
        ['NY', 'NY', 'New York', '40.76', '73.98']] 
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df_result = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['state', 'city', 'county','latitude_fuze','longitude_fuze']) 
data = [['New York', 'JFK', '40.63', '-73.60'], 
        ['New York', 'JFK', '40.64', '-73.78'],
        ['Los Angeles', 'LAX', '33.94', '-118.41'],
        ['Chicago', 'ORD', '40.98', '73.90'],
        ['San Francisco', 'SFO', '40.62', '73.38']]
df_airports = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['municipality_name', 'airport_code', 'latitude_air','longitude_air'])

# note the conversion to float

lon1 = df_result["longitude_fuze"].astype(float)
lat1 = df_result["latitude_fuze"].astype(float)
lon1 = df_result["longitude_fuze"].astype(float)
lon2 = df_airports['longitude_air'].astype(float)
lat2 = df_airports['latitude_air'].astype(float)

# using the haversine implementation above

df_result['haversine_dist'] = haversine_array(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2)
```

Now you will get:

```py
>>> df_result['haversine_dist']
0      10.036708
1      18.314266
2    3987.270064
3      25.354970
4      52.895712
Name: haversine_dist, dtype: float64
```

*Hope that helped!*

Comment: Thanks, but when I run that, I see that all haversine results are the same; all are 52.895712.  It looks like it's looping, but it only uses the last item for the calculation.  What am I missing here?

Comment: I've updated the answer and renamed the numpy implementation of the haversine function. Hope this now works for you too.

Comment: Yeap, that works perfect!  I checked it on this site.  

https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Answer (score 1):

It's  because you are passing the series data, instead, you need to pass single values..

```
# Below variables are going to have series data
lon1 = df["longitude_fuze"]
lat1 = df["latitude_fuze"]
lon2 = df["longitude_air"]
lat2 = df["latitude_air"]
```

Instead you can pick the value at particular index, for example, values at index 0:

```
lon1 = df["longitude_fuze"].iloc[0]
lat1 = df["latitude_fuze"].iloc[0]
lon2 = df["longitude_air"].iloc[0]
lat2 = df["latitude_air"].iloc[0]
```

With these values, now you can make call to your function:

```
df['haversine_dist'] = haversine(lon1,lat1,lon2,lat2)
```

Or you can even do this in loop if you want to evaluate the values for all of the values in those columns:

```
for i in df.index:
    lon1 = df["longitude_fuze"].iloc[i]
    lat1 = df["latitude_fuze"].iloc[i]
    lon2 = df["longitude_air"].iloc[i]
    lat2 = df["latitude_air"].iloc[i]

    df.loc[i, 'haversine_dist'] = haversine(lon1,lat1,lon2,lat2)
```

Comment: When I run that, all rows in df['haversine_dist'] are the same number; all are 52.895712.  The logic kind of looks right, final solution doesn't make any sense.  It's only doing the calculation for the last item in the index.

Comment: Make sure the call to the function is inside the loop, I think you are doing that outside the loop

Comment: There was small error as well, I fixed that